# Фиксированная комбинация, сгенерированная случайно, для конкретного пользователя

Tags: sql

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ случайного вывода данных, но чтобы при этом они не изменялись каждый раз?

Например, есть таблица вопросов для тестирования, содержащая, например, вопросы `1,5,9,20`. Мне нужно выбрать случайный данные из таблицы для пользователя с id 5 - например, `20,5,1,9,` а для пользователя с `id 20` - другую комбинацию. Если пользователь с `id 5` запрашивает свои вопросы - у него должна быть комбинация (`1,5,9,20`), а не новая, случайно сгенерированная.

Можно, конечно, один раз сгенерировать последовательность для каждого и внести в таблицу. Но как сделать, чтобы по `id` пользователя выводились определённые рандомные последовательности, а не просто рандомные данные? Можно ли как-то по синусоиде, либо ещё какой-нибудь функции перемешать вопросы?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как `seed` передать значение `id` на функцию `Rand()`

попробуйте это просто `order by rand(id)`

так как `seed` каждый раз выполняется одинаково

Answer (score 1):

перевод (с добавлениями) [ответа с англоязычного so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/4827341)

примеры вывода одной случайной строки (лимит можно изменить или вообще убрать) для *MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2 и Oracle*.

для получения воспроизводимой последовательности надо использовать `seed` на основе, например, `id` пользователя (привёл информацию для известных мне серверов):

- MySQL. `seed` можно задать параметром функции [`rand()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

  ```
  SELECT column FROM table
  ORDER BY RAND(seed)
  LIMIT 1
  ```
- PostgreSQL. `seed` можно задать с помощью [`setseed`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-set.html):

  ```
  SELECT setseed(seed);
  SELECT column FROM table
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 1
  ```
- Microsoft SQL Server.:

  ```
  SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  ```
- IBM DB2

  ```
  SELECT column, RAND() as IDX 
  FROM table 
  ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
  ```
- Oracle:

  ```
  SELECT column FROM
  ( SELECT column FROM table
  ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
  WHERE rownum = 1
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте таблицу со столбцами {id_user, id_quest}
Эту таблицу наполняйте для каждого пользователя вопросами, выбирая их из таблицы вопросов случайным образом.